# MySQL SELECT query condition not as expected - what is correct format?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to draw results from a table where `di_rl_id = 9` and any of the following is also true:

`di_status = 'APPROVED'`, `di_status = 'PENDING'`, `di_status = 'SUSPENDED'`.

The query I have is the following, however it doesn't match the condition I'm looking for, as it returns rows where the condition I have in mind is not met, e.g. where `di_rl_id != 9`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM d_info
WHERE di_status =  'PENDING'
OR di_status =  'APPROVED'
OR di_status =  'SUSPENDED'
AND di_rl_id =  '9'
```

Am I missing a special keyword or something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to separate off your OR clauses from your AND clause. This way one of the first three conditions will be true, AND `di_rl_id='9'` will always be true.

```
SELECT * 
FROM d_info
WHERE (di_status =  'PENDING'
OR di_status =  'APPROVED'
OR di_status =  'SUSPENDED')
AND di_rl_id =  '9'
```

The AND operator has higher precedence than OR, just like multiplication has higher precedence than addition. This is why you're getting the wrong resultset. You can read about operator precedence [on the MySQL docs.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: To explain what happened before, AND has higher precedence than OR, so the last pair (=Suspended AND =9) happened first, then OR =Pending OR =Approved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to separate the OR clauses from the AND clause.You must add the parentheses

```
SELECT * 
FROM d_info
WHERE (di_status =  'PENDING'
OR di_status =  'APPROVED'
OR di_status =  'SUSPENDED')
AND di_rl_id =  '9'
```